# Determining if file is already imported or not in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here in the below code I'm dynamically importing the file based on the locale and adding the Locale manually to browser using IntlProvider.

So the question is it will be called multiple times in the project if locale is being updated and **I need to determine if the file is already imported** then I need to skip these steps. Is there any way to do that?

```
const locale = navigator.language
            || 'en-US';   
React.useEffect(() => {
    addLocaleData(require( `intl/locale-data/jsonp/${locale}` ));   
}, []);
```

Comment: *"...it will be called multiple times in the project..."* Why would you do that?

Comment: In case if locale is being updated then again it will import, but if the file is already imported then it'll be best not to import again and add bloat to application.

Comment: So keep track of the locales you've imported....? I'm not seeing what the question is.

Comment: if you only wish to import it once i'm not sure why you need the hook at all.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep track of all the imports and importing only when its not present. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @DamianGreen this code is part of a component in my project. I have just added the code which is necessary, you can ignore the hook.

Answer (score 1):

This is client side code and will be rendered for each device/user.

I believe this might be better handled with an array of successfully loaded languages. Perhaps in a parent component.

```
let loadedLanguages = [];

...

loadedLanguages.push(`${locale}`);
```

The same might also be accomplished by using Local Storage and storing those items/data which are needed. This should better persist the information and reduce loads.

Comment: Isn't there any predefined library or function to do this and will be more optimized?

Comment: this code is incorrect, `let` should be lowercase and it will continue to push the same item onto the array

Comment: Thanks I made some adjustments above. The placement and logic will need to be written as well, to check the array and whether the locale has been loaded successfully, etc.